# Angular 2 tutorial - Misunderstanding with bindings

Tags: angularjs, angular

The question is at the end.

I'm learning Angular (angular 2). I know already Angular 1.5.

I'm doing the [official tutorial of angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and I don't understand one point at the chapter 3.Master/Detail.

Here is the [live example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-2/ts/eplnkr.html)

**CODE1**

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
</li>
```

When we click on the hero, we lunch the function *onSelect(hero)*

```
onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

Then, the following code appears.

**CODE2**

```
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
    <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My question:** 
When I change the value of the input with the *[(ngModel)]*, the text of the CODE1 change. Why? Because I have tried with a similar code with angular 1.5 and the text of CODE1 doesn't update.

I want to change with the input, the text of {{selectedHero.name}} and not {{hero.name}}

- *SelectedHero* is equal to *hero* but not the opposite isn't, is it?
- How to give *selectedHero* the value of *hero* with *onSelect()* and not to affect *hero* when i update *selectedHero* with the input (but change of course *{{selectedHero.name}}*)?

**EDIT:** Because of the Misunderstanding of my question, I try to reformulate:

When I change the value in the input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name", I want to change the value of {{selectedHero.name}} but not to change the value of {{hero.name}}. How can I succeed that? Thank you.

**EDIT 2 *QT Ray* gives the Answer in comments.**

We have to copy hero to  succeed.

We need to replace

```
this.selectedHero = hero;
```

by

```
this.selectedHero = Object.assign({}, hero);
```

or with deep copy (with lodash)

```
this.selectedHero = _.cloneDeep(hero)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SelectedHero is equal to hero but not the opposite isn't, is it?

In that situation, yes. SelectedHero and hero are the same. SelectedHero doesn't exist without selecting a hero.

When your code is loaded, selectedHero is probably something like:

`public selectedHero: IHero`

And in your constructor, you may have

`this.selectedHero = null`

selectedHero is not defined until you click a hero and then they become the same thing.

You could select another hero and then that Hero becomes the selectedHero.

> How to give selectedHero the value of hero with onSelect() and not to affect hero when i update selectedHero with the input (but change of course {{selectedHero.name}})?

You would need to get rid of the () around the ngModel. So it should say [ngModel]. The () binds the ngModel directive to the event. The [] lets the element know that it's an attribute. The click is fine, you will still pass that information to the element.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the one-way binding but I want to change with the input, the text of {{selectedHero.name}} and not {{hero.name}}. Is it possible?

Comment: I have reformulate the question, sorry for the Disagreement.

Comment: Sure, here's a link to the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ttCYeq0HqVPcwbEdHyyA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but {{selectedHero.name}} isn't updated when i write in the input.

Comment: Ahh! I understand the question. That's interesting. I've never had to do that. I don't think you can do that. The two objects are one of the same. We're explicitly setting it to the same value. Let me play with it a bit

Comment: So yes, this doesn't exist in angular 2. We used to be able to use < and that would handle it. Now you'll either have to use cloning in typescript or lodash to handle it. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137687/discussion-between-wandrille-and-qt-ray).

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html

> If you have a one-way binding to ngModel with [] syntax, changing the value of the domain model in the component class will set the value in the view. If you have a two-way binding with [()] syntax (also known as 'banana-box syntax'), the value in the UI will always be synced back to the domain model in your class as well.`

You are using two way binding which is why the hero you selected in CODE1 changes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But with a one Way binding [ ], i can't change the value of the CODE2 in {{selectedHero.name}} and want to change {{selectedHero.name}} but not  to change {{hero.name}}

Comment: I have reformulate the question, sorry for the Disagreement.

Comment: No problem! Glad you figured it out!